# What do you call the specific front covering of an airplane engine?

Tags: word-request

[image]

This plane debris shows the very part I am referring to, the front covering of an aircraft engine. Is there a specific word or phrase used to refer to this?

Comment: A [engine] cowl lip.

Comment: It's either part of the inlet casing or the exhaust casing. But whichever it is, the "name" isn't something the average native Anglophone would know, so I think this question is Off Topic

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network, https://aviation.stackexchange.com/ in particular

Comment: I would say the *cowl* or the *cowling*, but I agree that this isn't really general English usage and should probably be migrated.